# which algorithm will be appropriately used for contact intimacy?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

i need to implement a project with visual intimacy between persons,can anyone recommends an algorithm for person's intimacy in phone contact?

intimacy attenuate over time(the intimacy attenuates automatically if you havnt click/dial it for a long time).

Assume in my address book：

```
Person     Intimacy(0-100%)
   A         40%
   B         80%
   C         10%
```

A's intimacy needs raise after i call A ,like this

```
Person     Intimacy(0-100%)
   A         42%
   B         80%
   C         10%
```

nothing happens after follow 5 days, A,B,C's intimacy need decline,like this

```
Person     Intimacy(0-100%)
   A         37%
   B         78%
   C         8%
```

thanks for everyone's answer

Comment: Can you define "contact intimacy" and "visual intimacy" in mathematical terms?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to determine how well you know someone in your address book based on how often you call them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> intimacy attenuate over time(the intimacy attenuates automatically if you havnt click/dial it for a long time).

You could use an [exponential decaying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) number expressed as a [Half Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life)

```
double intimacy = Math.pow(0.5, time / halfLife);
```

I would be surprised if there is a standard solution to your problem.

---

A typical graph has a shape like this.

[image]

---

> Are you asking for an algorithm to determine how well you know someone in your address book based on how often you call them?

For this you could use an [Exponential Weighted Moving Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) Again, I just speculating what might be useful.

> could you express more detail?

From the data you gave, the half life is about 28 days. You can use the EWMA on a daily basis like this

```
double alpha = 1.0/28;

score = (contacted ? 1 : 0) * alpha + score * (1 - alpha);
```

e.g.

```
contacted, prev score, score
TRUE        40%     42%
FALSE       42%     41%
FALSE       41%     39%
FALSE       39%     38%
FALSE       38%     36%
FALSE       36%     35%
```

---

Say the decay is 28 days and I call the same person for 200 days. The score looks like

```
double score = 0;
double alpha = 1.0 / 28;
boolean contacted = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    score = (contacted ? 1 : 0) * alpha + score * (1 - alpha);
    System.out.printf("%.3f%n", score);
}
```

prints

```
0.036
0.070
0.103
... deleted ...
0.999
0.999
0.999
```

Its not possible for the score to larger than the maximum value (in this case the `1` in the equation).

Comment: Peter, how do you define `halfLife`? `120/2 = 60`?

Comment: @AlexR half life, e.g. like radiation, is the time you expect there to be half. After double this it will be 1/4, three times => 1/8 etc.

Comment: @AlexR OP must know from his problem domain how long it takes for "intimacy" to drop to half in a period of no contact.

Comment: Peter & Marko, thank your for clarification. Very interesting.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i edited my post. i think you are the expert

Comment: @PeterLawrey it is very useful for your answer, could you express more detail?

Comment: From the data you gave, the half life is about 28 days. You can use the EWMA on a daily basis like this `score = (contacted ? 1.0/28 : 0.0) + (1.0 - 1.0/28) * score`

Comment: @bigjava see the example above

Comment: @PeterLawrey when i call person A many times, the score with person A will be 99%(lower than 100%),how can i implement above?please give me an advice,thanks

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks, exponential decaying algorithm works well. EWMA method smooth flourish/decay. howerver, the score will go higher than 100% after i call A 100000 times, are there a mathematical method do the opposite thing from exponential decaying，approach 100%　but lower than it?

Comment: @bigjava It will never be more than one impulse. If you are getting this you have an error of some kind. I have added some sample code.